# React Navigation or Reack Hooks - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Using React Native to navigate between screens, what are the differences between using React Navigation or simply navigating between screens using hooks and functions. Is React Navigation better?

Comment: What do you mean by navigating between screens using hooks and functions? Creating your own navigation module?

Comment: for example, I'm in my app's home and I click on the button to go to the details screen, and I do this using just useState, can I create a whole app like this, or is this wrong?

Comment: Well of course you could do that. The benefit of using react navigation however is that you also get things like history and standardized components and interfaces for things like the header and the tab bar. There's also the time cost of creating your own navigation system.

Comment: Thank you man, I've developed apps both ways and thought that maybe it would be wrong to just use useState. And do you know which of the two ways has more performance, or is it the same?

Answer (score 0):

From the official docs: "React Navigation is made up of some core utilities and those are then used by navigators to create the navigation structure in your app".
Without the navigation structure you would not have the hooks, functions, screens to navigate.
React Navigation gives you all the tools to build a navigation flow in your app.